# html list items trigger spring boot controller

Tags: java, html, spring-boot

I have a drop down button, with options of export to CSV and export to excel.
When i click each of the option, i want to trigger the respective controller method to download file.

My html code is like the following:

```
<div class="row col-xs-2" style="position:relative;top:10px;">
                             <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary normal-btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                             Export  <span class="caret"></span>
                             </button>
                             <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <form action="#" data-th-action="@{/coaExport}" method="POST">
                                    <li><a type="submit" name="action" value="csv" id="coaExport_CS1V" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Export to .CSV</a></li>
                                    <li><a type="submit" name="action" value="excel" id="coaExport_exc1el" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Export to Excel</a></li>
                                </form>
                             </ul>
                          </div>'
```

My controller data is :

```
    @GetMapping(value="/coaExport", params="action=csv")
    public void exportCOACSV(HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Export CSV");
   }

    @GetMapping(value="/coaExport", params="action=excel")
    public void exportCOAExcel(HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Export Excel.");
}
```

Comment: You're having `GetMapping`s, but you're doing a post.

Comment: Oh! and your items should be `button`s or `input`s.

Comment: Why you just can't do simple <a href = /coaExport?action=csv> Export to .CSV

Answer (score 0):

The above solution

```
<a href = /coaExport?action=csv> Export to .CSV
```

works. thanks for helping